# Can't log into Ubuntu. How to remove the ATI Catalyst driver?

Tags: drivers, hp, 14.10, catalyst

Installing the Catalyst drivers on Ubuntu 14.10 HP Zbook 14 broke the system - it can't start the X display because it crashes now, and I can't switch to tty or command-line to remove the driver as that does nothing.

How can I repair the system?

Comment: how did you install the driver? did you try booting to recovery mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When booting, press and hold <kbd>shift</kbd> key to get the GRUB menu, and enter the **recovery mode**:

[image]

2. Then drop into the root shell prompt:

[image]

3. You will be given a command line interface. Issue these commands to remove ATI drivers:

> sudo apt-get remove fglrx
>      sudo apt-get remove fglrx-updates

If you have manually installed the ATI driver by downloading the installer package, you can use it to remove the driver as well:

> sudo ./amd-driver-installer-*.run --uninstall

---

You will need to install the open source ATI driver as well:

> sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati